# JavaFX FXML injection timing

Tags: javafx, fxml

In my GUI program I have an accordion with GridPanes which are injected into a controller. After the stage is shown however, one of the GridPanes (the last one of a large number of panes to be injected) has a null value and causes a nullpointerexception. It has been declared in the controller with the FXML tag.

If I pause the program in the debugger and then proceed, the GridPane is not null, but causes an "Exception in Application start method".

Has anyone ever come across this type of behaviour? Is it possible that there is a timing (different threads) problem?

Comment: Edit your question to provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - ensure it is minimal, complete, executable and contains everything needed for somebody to replicate the issue with nothing else.

Comment: Why would there be a threading problem?  JavaFX is single threaded from a user programming perspective.  Are you creating threads?  If so, you really will need to supply some sample code if you want somebody to help troubleshoot the issue.